# Mouse and keyboard stop working after suspend or screensaver lock

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, mouse, suspend, screensaver

If I leave the computer and let it run into screensaver and lock the screen, the mouse left click won't go back to work. If I suspend the computer, the keyboard won't get back to work. It started after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04. Any tips to solve this problem?

The follwing lines I got on `dmesg` after the problem happened

```
[30536.564415] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[30536.565725] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[30536.568466] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[30536.569790] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[30536.571123] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[30536.571126] psmouse.c: issuing reconnect request
```

and that after I tried to plug again my USB mouse:

```
[31570.040088] usb 6-1: USB disconnect, address 2
[31573.490095] usb 6-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
[31573.687376] input: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/input/input12
[31573.687544] generic-usb 0003:045E:0084.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
```

Comment: well... I updated to the kernel 2.6.38-9 and I guess it is working fine now...